# сортировка по значению

Tags: java, сортировка, map, java-stream

Необходимо получить HashMap с ключом groupID, значением: кол-во студентов с одинаковым значением group_id.

```java
public class StudentDTO {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private  Integer studentID;
    private Integer groupId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения такой задачи -- получения хэш-таблицы -- проще всего использовать Stream API, где для группировки по полю/геттеру используется `Collectors.groupingBy`, для подсчёта количества с типом `Integer` -- `Collectors.summingInt`:

```java
List<StudentDTO> list = ...; // список студентов
Map<Integer, Integer> countById = list
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            StudentDTO::getGroupID,
            Collectors.summingInt(stud -> 1)
        ));
```

Также можно считать с типом `Long` с коллектором `Collectors.counting`:

```java
Map<Integer, Long> longCountById = list
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            StudentDTO::getGroupID,
            Collectors.counting()
        ));
```

---

Также можно получить результат при помощи обычного цикла и метода [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();

for (StudentDTO student : list) {
    result.merge(student.getGroupID(), 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

---

Следует отметить, что хэш-таблица не является сортированной и порядок элементов внутри таблицы не гарантируется.

Для получения сортированной таблицы *по ключу* можно использовать `TreeMap`.

Для сортировки элементов *по значению* следует отсортировать множество элементов хэш-таблицы `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>`, которое возвращается из `Map::entrySet`, и пересохранить результат в `LinkedHashMap`, поддерживающую порядок вставки элементов:

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> sortedByFreq = result.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) // или по убыванию Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            LinkedHashMap::new,
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue)
        ));
```